# SASS/SCSS: How can I use Hex and RGB Color in same $color map?

Tags: css, sass

I have an Idea to create something different using SCSS What I want to
achieve is very simple.

use two different color types HEX and RGB in same map key.

and Using it If I want to create a css color class with proprety contain RGB value
it will be possible and same thing for Hex Color.

**My Full Code :**

```
@function hexToRGB($hex) {
  @return red($hex), green($hex), blue($hex);
}

$red-50:  #FEF6F5         !default;

$red: () !default;
$red: map-merge(
    (
        "red-50": hexToRGB($red-50),
    ),
    $red
);

$colors: () !default;
$colors: map-merge(
    (
        "red":       $red,
    ),
    $colors
);

@each $name, $value in $colors {
    @each $shade, $color in $value {
        .color-#{$shade} {
            /** RGB Color **/
            --color-example1: rgba(#{$color}, 1);
            /** Hex Color **/
            --color-example2: #{$color};
        }
    }
}
```

**The Result that I want to get after compiling to CSS :**

```
.color-red-50 {
  /** RGB Color **/
  --color-example1: rgba(254, 246, 245, 1);
  /** Hex Color **/
  --color-example2: #FEF6F5;
}
```

What I want from these examples is to use different color types (Hex and RGB)
and use them on the same map $colors key.

Comment: Your example number one is actually standard SCSS behaviour already, you can pass in a hex variable to an rgb ( or rgba) property and it will automatically be compiled to the relevant output. With this in mind the need for the function disappears with the use of a consistency in your stylesheet.

Comment: Can you Explain more with example please because I'm new with SASS and thank you for your help